# Word for changing abbreviation into text

Tags: word-request, abbreviations

On the Internet, I found the phrase

> Function changes a short abbreviation into a text block

For instance, an abbreviation of "US" changes to "United States".

I feel there should be a single verb to express this act. But I can't find it.

In some other languages, e.g. in Russian, Ukrainian, there is such a word with the meaning of "open", "unveil", "open out", "open up", "release". Like a flower or locked box opening. What is it in English? Or would any of the mentioned words work?

Comment: Got it from first google search: "antonym of abbreviate" (https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01TcfQy7kpGMG-yTVFjGMN3XQkSag%3A1612961653107&source=hp&ei=ddcjYK_qA4yIU5y5sKgB&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYCPlhc5G5YmXfky5MDdN8XrZ24wpG2kn&q=antonyms+of+abbreviate&oq=antonyms+of+abbreviate&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADIECAAQCjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgsILhDHARCjAhCTAjoCCC46CAguEMcBEKMCUOfTigFYxu2KAWDp7ooBaABwAHgAgAGPBIgBswqSAQczLTEuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjv-Peyrt_uAhUMxBQKHZwcDBUQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: @Sphinx I've never used the verb "abbreviate" before. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called **expanding** the abbreviation.

- **expand** v **3 b** : to write out in full.  *Expand all abbreviations* ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expand))